# When I use hmset in php redis, why does it sucess if I use 'test_a' as the key, it fails if use 'test'

Tags: php, redis

```
require_once libfile('class/myredis');
$myredis = myredis::instance(6381);
$res = $myredis->hmset('test', array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2));
var_dump($res);

/*the result: bool(false);*/

require_once libfile('class/myredis');
$myredis = & myredis::instance(6381);
$res = $myredis->hmset('test_a', array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2));
var_dump($res);
```

/* the result: bool(true);*/

I can not understand why, are there any other differences between the two keys, 'test' 'test_a', Thank you for your help!

Comment: Not sure, what happens if you unset($res) in between the calls?

Comment: or remove the &, or unset($myredis) ...

Comment: My guess: your database already has a key named `test` that isn't a Hash (probably a string), so the call fails because it being the wrong data type.

Comment: I guess you are right, maybe the 'test' is not a Hash, How can I know whether it is a Hash or not in PHP REDIS? thank you very much.

Comment: I tried  remove the & or unset($res) in between the calls. It is still   the same. when I execute from CLI: php delete_expired_invitation.php  Then it echos bool(false)
bool(true)

Comment: @wlstony: the [`TYPE`](http://redis.io/commands/type) command will tell you that... Which PHP Redis library are you using? In any case, use `redis-cli` (or just telnet to your Redis server) for this type of interaction... much simpler than coding it in PHP IMO

Comment: @Itamar Haber, Thank you for your help. I tried again as you told,               127.0.0.1:6379> type test
string
127.0.0.1:6379>. 'test' is a string. Thank you!